# Breeze get Metadata from another location

Tags: breeze

I think I have a small stupid problem with breeze.
Maybe somebody know the answer? I wanna change the url where breeze is looking for the metadata.

breeze tries to connect to:

```
http://localhost:7048/DynamicsNAV71/OData/Company('CRONUS%20(Schweiz)%20AG')/Metadata
```

instead of where it is:

```
http://localhost:7048/DynamicsNAV71/OData/$metadata
```

Somebody knows how to change this?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to change the metadata location, one approach would be to intercept the ajax call and change the url like this:

```
var ajaxAdapter = breeze.config.getAdapterInstance('ajax');
ajaxAdapter.requestInterceptor = function (requestInfo) {
    if (requestInfo.config.url === "http://localhost:7048/DynamicsNAV71/OData/Company('CRONUS%20(Schweiz)%20AG')/Metadata") {
        requestInfo.config.url = "http://localhost:7048/DynamicsNAV71/OData/$metadata";
    }
}
```

For more info see the *Configure a specific AJAX request with requestInterceptor* topic here:

http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/controlling-ajax

Comment: Thanks but i switched to jaydata, for me it's a lot easier ;)